# Drawing heart in mathematica

Tags: geometry, plane-curves, mathematica

It's not really a typical math question. Today, while studying graphs, I suddenly got inquisitive about whether there exists a function that could possibly draw a heart-shaped graph. Out of sheer curiosity, I clicked on Google, which took me to [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html).

The page seems informative, and I am glad to learn certain new things! Now I am interested in drawing them by my own using Mathematica. So my question is: is it possible to draw them in Mathematica? If yes, please show me how.

Comment: The following links may be useful to you:

http://xahlee.org/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/Cardioid_dir/cardioid.html

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GeneratingACardioidIIICirclesPassingThroughAPoint/

There is also a differential geometry with mathematica book you may want to look up if the links don't give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Duck-shaped heart: `SphericalPlot3D[Log[u] + Sin[v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the fifth function in the link you [mentioned](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html) (which I thought it was the most similar to a heart):

```
PolarPlot[(Sin[t]Sqrt[Abs[Cos[t]]])/(Sin[t]+7/5)-2Sin[t]+2, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Similarly, [using W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolarPlot+(Sin[t]+Sqrt[Abs[Cos[t]]])/(Sin[t]+%2B+7/5)+-+2+Sin[t]+%2B+2):

[image]

Comment: Now that's love

Comment: By the way, I couldn't paste the address to W|A into a link (maybe some character is breaking the <a> tags). However, the same code for Mathematica works in W|A.

Comment: For links to WA you have to replace the square brackets with parenthesis

Comment: Like this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolarPlot%20((Sin(t)Sqrt(Abs(Cos(t))))/(Sin(t)%2B7/5)-2Sin(t)%2B2)

Comment: @belisarius: I didn't know that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 34):

You can plot [Taubin's heart surface](http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/surfaces/taubin%27s_heart_surface/cr/rn/yc/) using `ContourPlot3D`:

```
ContourPlot3D[(2 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 - (1/10) x^2 z^3 - y^2 z^3 == 0,
              {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5},
              Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8, Red]]
```

[image: Taubin's heart]

Answer (score 28):

Consider the map $T \colon \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2, \ (x,y) \mapsto (x, y+ \sqrt{|x|})$.  With a little examination, you can see that this will define a warping on the plane that will map the unit circle to a heart shaped curve: 
[image]

So if you know that a parametrization for the circle is $(\cos(t),\ \sin(t)),\  t\in [-\pi,\pi]$, then the parametrization for its heart-shaped image would be $(\cos(t),\ \sin(t) + \sqrt{|\cos(t)|}),\  t\in [-\pi,\pi]$. You can plot the curve with the following Mathematica code:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t] + Sqrt[Abs[Cos[t]]]}, {t, -Pi, Pi}]
```

Answer (score 9):

A somewhat late addition (I only found my yellowed notebooks containing these just now):

$$\left(2(1+\cos\,\varphi)\sin^3 t\qquad 2\cos\,\theta\;\sin^2 t \sin\,\varphi+\sin\,\theta\cos\,t\left(\cos\,2t-2\cos\,\varphi\;\sin^2 t-3\right)\right)^T$$

is a two-parameter family of curves that generate heart shapes for some values of $\theta$ and $\varphi$. They were derived from projections of a skewed version of the nephroid.

Here for instance is the case $\theta=\pi/4,\quad \varphi=\pi/2$:

[image: heart]

Answer (score 6):

The following inputs will plot the following 6 hearts in the picture below respectively.

```
ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 - x^2 y^3 == 0, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, MaxRecursion -> 5]

ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - (2 (x^2 + Abs[x] - 6))/(3 (x^2 + Abs[x] + 2)))^2 == 36, {x, -9, 9}, {y, -9, 9}, MaxRecursion -> 5]

ContourPlot[x^2 + (5/4 y - Sqrt[Abs[x]])^2 == 1, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},MaxRecursion -> 5]

ContourPlot[0 == (Sqrt[1 - (Abs[x/5] - 1)^2] - y/5 + 3/4) (ArcCos[1 - Abs[x/5]] - \[Pi] - y/5 + 3/4), {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12}, MaxRecursion -> 5]

PolarPlot[2 - 2 Sin[\[Theta]] + Sin[\[Theta]] Sqrt[Abs[Cos[\[Theta]]]]/(Sin[\[Theta]] + 1.4), {\[Theta], -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, MaxRecursion -> 5]

ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + (9 y^2)/4 + z^2 - 1)^3 - x^2 z^3 - (9 y^2 z^3)/80 == 0, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image: Sample Hearts]

I also came up with my own strictly algebraic equation that will plot the letters AB inside of a heart for my significant other.  The equation is...

$
\left(\left(\left(\left| y\right| -\frac{29}{20}\right)^2+(x-1)^2\right)^2+18 \left(\left(\left| y\right| -\frac{29}{20}\right)^2+\left(x-\frac{219}{100}\right)^2\right)-8 \left(\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^3-3 \left(x-\frac{39}{20}\right) \left(\left| y\right| -\frac{147}{100}\right)^2\right)-27\right)
$
$
\left(\left(\left(x+\frac{7}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right)^2+\frac{9}{2} \left(\left(x+\frac{7}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right)-4 \left(\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)^3-\left(x+\frac{7}{4}\right)^2 \left(2 y+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{27}{16}\right)
$
$
\left(\left(\left(x+\frac{7}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\right)^2+18 \left(\left(x+\frac{7}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\right)-8 \left(\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+\frac{3}{4}\right)^3-\left(x+\frac{7}{4}\right)^2 \left(2 y+\frac{9}{4}\right)\right)-27\right)
$
$
\sqrt{\frac{\left| \sqrt{\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+2\right)^2+\left(x+\frac{11}{4}\right)^2}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+2\right)^2+\left(x+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}-\frac{5}{2}\right| }{\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{11}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+2\right)^2}+\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+2\right)^2}-\frac{5}{2}}} \sqrt{\frac{\left| \sqrt{(y-2)^2+\left(x-\frac{9}{20}\right)^2}+\sqrt{(y+2)^2+\left(x-\frac{9}{20}\right)^2}-\frac{21}{5}\right| }{\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{9}{20}\right)^2+(y-2)^2}+\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{9}{20}\right)^2+(y+2)^2}-\frac{21}{5}}}
$
$
\left(\sqrt{\left(-x-\frac{11}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+\frac{7}{4}\right)^2}+\sqrt{\left(-x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2 y}{3}+\frac{7}{4}\right)^2}-\frac{5}{2}\right)
$
$
\left(\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+(y-2)^2}+\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+(y+2)^2}-\frac{21}{5}\right)
$
$
\left(\left((\left| y\right| +1)^2+(x-2)^2\right)^2-19 \left((\left| y\right| +1)^2-(x-2)^2\right)\right)
$
$
\left(\left(-\sqrt{\left| \frac{x}{2}\right| }+\frac{3 y}{10}+\frac{9}{10}\right)^2+\frac{x^2}{20}-5\right) = 0
$

The mathematica code is...

```
ContourPlot[0 == (x^2/20 + ((3 y)/10 + 9/10 - Sqrt[Abs[x/2]])^2 - 
 5) ((((2 y)/3 + 1/4)^2 + (x + 7/4)^2)^2 + 
 9/2 (((2 y)/3 + 1/4)^2 + (x + 7/4)^2) - 27/16 - 
 4 (((2 y)/3 + 1/4)^3 - (2 y + 3/2) (x + 7/4)^2)) (((x + 7/
     4)^2 + ((2 y)/3 + 3/4)^2)^2 + 
 18 ((x + 7/4)^2 + ((2 y)/3 + 3/4)^2) - 27 - 
 8 (((2 y)/3 + 3/4)^3 - (2 y + 9/4) (x + 7/4)^2)) (Sqrt[((2 y)/
    3 + 7/4)^2 + (-x - 11/4)^2] + 
 Sqrt[((2 y)/3 + 7/4)^2 + (-x - 3/4)^2] - 5/
 2) \[Sqrt](Abs[
   Sqrt[((2 y)/3 + 2)^2 + (x + 11/4)^2] + 
    Sqrt[((2 y)/3 + 2)^2 + (x + 3/4)^2] - 5/
    2]/(Sqrt[((2 y)/3 + 2)^2 + (x + 11/4)^2] + 
    Sqrt[((2 y)/3 + 2)^2 + (x + 3/4)^2] - 5/
    2)) ((((Abs[y] + 1)^2 + (x - 2)^2)^2 - 
  19 ((Abs[y] + 1)^2 - (x - 2)^2))) (((x - 1)^2 + (Abs[y] - 29/
     20)^2)^2 + 18 ((x - 219/100)^2 + (Abs[y] - 29/20)^2) - 27 - 
 8 ((x - 5/2)^3 - 3 (x - 39/20) (Abs[y] - 147/100)^2)) (Sqrt[(x - 
    1/2)^2 + (y - 2)^2] + Sqrt[(x - 1/2)^2 + (y + 2)^2] - 21/
 5) (Sqrt[
Abs[Sqrt[(x - 9/20)^2 + (y - 2)^2] + 
  Sqrt[(x - 9/20)^2 + (y + 2)^2] - 21/5]/(
Sqrt[(x - 9/20)^2 + (y - 2)^2] + Sqrt[(x - 9/20)^2 + (y + 2)^2] - 
 21/5)]), {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12}, MaxRecursion -> 7]
```

and the graph is...

[image: AB Algebraic Heart]

When using the ContourPlot function in Mathematica there are issues and you may get some noise.  So your image may not be as clean as mine.  Also it will take a while to plot it at MaxRecursion->7 so stand by.

Comment: Is there any easy way to write something to the Heart such as BEST?

Comment: @hhh There is not an easy way to do that or to write anything for that matter.  It would have to be calculated.

Answer (score 2):

Inigo Quilez has found a polar plot of a heart that doesn't require any of trigonometric functions:

> polar plot r = (0.322515 * abs(theta)^3 - 2.22907 * abs(theta)^2 + 4.13803 * abs(theta))/(6.0 - 1.59155 * abs(theta)), theta=-pi to pi

[Wolphram Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r+%3D+(0.322515+*+abs(theta)%5E3+-+2.22907+*+abs(theta)%5E2+%2B+4.13803+*+abs(theta))%2F(6.0+-+1.59155+*+abs(theta)),+theta%3D-pi+to+pi)

[Shadertoy live version](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsfGRn)

Answer (score 2):

A three-dimensional space curve with the shape of a red heart:

[image]

The Mathematica code for the image above is:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u]*(4*Sqrt[1 - v^2]*Sin[Abs[u]]^Abs[u]), v, 
  Sin[u]*(4*Sqrt[1 - v^2]*Sin[Abs[u]]^Abs[u])}, 
   {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, -1, 1}, Axes -> None, Mesh -> False, 
 Boxed -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Specularity[White, 10]}]
```

3D red heart with Mesh and lines:

[image]

Mathematica code for the image above:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u]*(4*Sqrt[1 - v^2]*Sin[Abs[u]]^Abs[u]), v, 
  Sin[u]*(4*Sqrt[1 - v^2]*Sin[Abs[u]]^Abs[u])}, {u, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {v, -0.97, 0.97}, PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Glow[Red], Specularity[White, 30], Opacity[0.15]], 
 Mesh -> 50, Background -> Black, MeshStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", Yellow, {{1.5, 1.5, 5}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}}, 
    Pi/6}}]
```

A variation on the use of the Taubin heart surface with hue:

[image]

Mathematica code for the last image above:

```
ContourPlot3D[(-1/10) x^2 z^3 - 
   y^2 z^3 + (2 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 == 0, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.4,
   1.4}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 60, 
 Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Red], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, Hue[z]]]
```

For more customized heart images, see the post in my website/blog:

https://knowledgemix.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/heart-to-heart-with-3d-math/

Answer (score 1):

This is really about plotting polar plots, parametric plots and implicitly defined functions in Mathematica.

This is the info on how to draw polar plots

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarPlot.html

Parametric plots

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot.html

This provides info on implicit plots

http://grosz.math.txstate.edu/~dhaz/prob_sets/LTs09cal1lab8.pdf

Comment: Am not getting how to plot the second and third graph in that page.

Comment: @Debanjan: Second is just an implicit plot, check out the link in my answer. Third is a parametric plot,  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a screen shot from this equation on Wolfram Alpha.  I don't have a license for Mathematica.

```
(x^2+y^2-1)^3 = x^2
```

[image]

Comment: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Heart_shapes_in_mathematics