# LOVE ly equations

Tags: graphing-functions

Is there a set of equations out there that gives a heart without any other marks?  It needs to be in the form of $y = f(x), r = f(\theta)$ or $X_T ,Y_T$ (parametric equations) There needs to be a variable '$a$', which gives a different shape for a different value of $a$.

Edit 1:Also, could you state the best value for $a$? This is opinion based, but it takes me ages to draw one using trial and error

Edit 2: Sorry guys, I am being a bit of a pain aren't I?! This has turned into a challenge now, but could you specify rad/deg, Parameters for $\theta, x/y, and T$? As I have said, I am going to draw this by hand, and I might even **LEGO** it, so can you give me something suitable for **LEGO**ing?

Comment: Reference: [Heart Curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html), [cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid).

Comment: You could take a look at the many solutions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12098/drawing-heart-in-mathematica) and see if any meet your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An equation that generates a beautiful or unique shape for motivating students in mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808650/an-equation-that-generates-a-beautiful-or-unique-shape-for-motivating-students-i)  If you search the site for heart equation you find several

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the cardioid, one form of which is given by
$$
r=2a(1+\cos\theta)
$$

$\theta \in [0, 2\pi[$ say ( so radians.)

To plot by hand plug in the values of $\theta$ e.g.

When $\theta = 0$ then $r=4a$

When $\theta = \pi/2$ then $r=2a$

When $\theta = \pi$ then $r=0$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid